# How to redirect default Devise sign_in url to 404 page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make custom sign_in url for my app. So I created a new route in `routes.rb`. my code sample is

```
  devise_scope :user do
   get 'site-admin/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

But still`'users/sign_in'` is also going to login page.How to redirect `'users/sign_in'` to 404 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes), all you have to do in your *routes.rb* is this:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]
as :user do
  get 'site-admin/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
end
```

Comment: yes...it worked.But I need to add omniauth gem in gemfile  and :omniauthable to devise model

Comment: And...what it's the problem with that?